# How do I load a custom font face in SCSS files?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Despite hours of research into this, I can't seem to get any of the solutions to work. I'm trying to load a custom font face into my app and so far this is what I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'proximaNova-bold';
  src: asset_url('/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNova-Bold.eot');
  src: asset_url('/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNova-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset_url('/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNova-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
       asset_url('/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
       asset_url('/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNova-Bold.svg#ProximaNova-Bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is what my file tree looks like:

[image]

NOTE: I'm using `asset_url` because this will be deployed to Heroku (and I believe that the urls are different in production vs. in development)

And here is the error message that I'm getting:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ProximaNova-`Bold.ttf"):`
```

Comment: I don't think so your asset_url is throwing the error but  as per the error given it is "/ProximaNova-`Bold.ttf". Why there is a ` in between

Comment: Ah wait, so is it the asset_url that's throwing the error?? And what did you mean by in between?

Answer (score 0):

move font files from subfolder fonts/proxima_nova_bold to fonts (app/assets/fonts)
and here is how you import it

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
    src: asset-url('ProximaNova-Bold.eot');
    src: asset-url('ProximaNova-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('ProximaNova-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was the error in how I structured my file tree?

Comment: my understanding, if you put in subfolder under (app/assets/fonts) you have to tell rails to trace subfolder